# Print arrays by fields Separate

Tags: arrays, drupal

i have arrays like this :

```
Array
(
    [477] => Array
        (
            [nid] => 477
            [changed] => 1510506071
            [created] => 1510506071
            [title] => mother
            [status] => 1
        )

    [480] => Array
        (
            [nid] => 480
            [changed] => 1510506071
            [created] => 1510506071
            [title] => hello
            [status] => 1
        )

    [481] => Array
        (
            [nid] => 481
            [changed] => 1510506071
            [created] => 1510506071
            [title] => name
            [status] => 1
        )
```

i need to render arrays by field Separate and use `print_r($result[''][nid])` OR print_r($result[]nid) but dont work !

Any help on doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($yourArray as $array){
    print_r(array['nid']);
}
```

Comment: i have a lot of fields...!

Comment: I dont understand what do you need? as a result you need new array with all 'nid's??

Comment: give my example of result array you need

Comment: my mistake , Thanks @Zeljka Problem fixed

Comment: i still dont understand what do you need? maybe you need just in my code print_r($array); instead of print_r($array['nid']);

Comment: I want this too :D

Comment: learn more about foreach and lloops :) you can do everything with it